# How to join with table that have no record?

Tags: mysql

I have this two table products and wishlist. Here is the structure

[image]

And here is wishlist

[image]

Here is my query

```
SELECT a.productId,productName,isNew,isHot,productImage,a.categoryId,productPrice,productDescription, 
IF(b.UserId = NULL, 1,0) as isLiked
from products a LEFT JOIN  wishlist b on (a.productId = b.productId) and (a.categoryId = b.categoryId)
where b.userId = 'usr001'
```

But the the query is not showing any records, when I delete the condition it showing the records of products.

So I want to showing the records of product even using the condition, how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are your keys (productId, wishlistId, categoryId, userid) varchars instead of integers, typically with AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: it is not `auto_increment` i generate the id

Comment: Why is that?  So you can have keys like 'usr001'?

Comment: It's a bad idea, and violates the rule that keys should not have information encoded in them.  In your scheme, you are using 6 bytes, with a maximum of 999 users supported, whereas, an unsigned smallint would allow you to support up to 64k users in 2 bytes per row.  There are similar arguments to be made for all your other tables, where a 4 byte unsigned integer will support up to 4.2 billion.  There is no calculation needed, no table locks or anything else to support high concurrency and fast inserts using AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment. so it is better to use the AUTO_INCREMENT as the primary and foreign? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: You use AUTO_INCREMENT for your primary keys in each table.  A foreign key is as the name suggests,  "the key for a foreign table".  They just need to match the datatype and precision of the other table.  So in the wishlist table, productId would need to be an unsigned integer, assuming that is what it was defined to be in the product table.  When you create a new wishlist row, you store the same productId number as the productId for that product.  You can also add foreign key constraints that help protect your system from bad data by enforcing referential integrity between tables.

Comment: No worries, and one note: make sure all your tables are using engine=InnoDB.  You won't get good performance, ACID compliance, referential integrity, row level locking etc, without it.  You can alter your existing tables to be InnoDB even if you have already built them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected
Products

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | product 1 |
|  2 | product 2 |
|  3 | product 3 |
|  4 | product 4 |
|  5 | product 5 |
+----+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

create table wishlist
(userid int, productid int,name varchar(20));
insert into wishlist values
(1,1,'product 1'),
(1,3,'product 3');

select p.id,p.name,if(w.productid is null, 0 , 1 ) isliked
from products p
left join wishlist w on w.productid = p.id and p.name = w.name and w.userid = 1
order by p.id limit 5;

+----+-----------+---------+
| id | name      | isliked |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | product 1 |       1 |
|  2 | product 2 |       0 |
|  3 | product 3 |       1 |
|  4 | product 4 |       0 |
|  5 | product 5 |       0 |
+----+-----------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't see a difference between my model and yours - It would help if you added sample data as text to the question together with the table defintions(as text).

Answer (score 1):

Use `b.userId = 'usr001'` in `ON Clause` instead of `where clause`

```
SELECT a.productId,productName,isNew,isHot,productImage,a.categoryId,productPrice,productDescription, 
IF(b.UserId is NULL, 1,0) as isLiked
from products a LEFT JOIN  wishlist b on (a.productId = b.productId) and (a.categoryId = b.categoryId)
and b.userId = 'usr001'
```

Comment: it is work like i expected, but when i add a record to `wishlist`, every `isLiked` is `0`

Comment: yes, cause there is no record in your wishlist @MyNameIs

Comment: so the problem was here `b.userId = null` to `b.userId is null`

Comment: @MyNameIs, yaa you are right, I didn't have noticed anyway, glad that you found your solutions